# Program stuck in infinite lop during single for loop calculation

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I am new to c++ programming and am taking a computational physics class where we are analyzing the problem of percolation on a square lattice using a single-cluster algorithm. My professor has given us some base code, and asked us to modify it as well as write some additional code and scripts within and without this specific program. I have written the majority of the code and scripts necessary to solve and plot this problem, but I am having an issue with my main data output program, specifically that of an infinite loop when I set an input parameter to any value other than 0.

Three main function comprise this program, namely LATTICE::LATTICE, CLUSTER::grow, and CUSTER::print, and also uses a standard Mersenne Twister header file. The heavily modified, commented, and toyed with c++ program is as follows:

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "MersenneTwister.h"

using namespace std;

class PARAMS
{
public:
  int Nlin; // linear size of lattice
  double pr; // probability for a site
  double Nclust; // number of clusters in a bin
  double Nbin; // number of bins of data to output
  int SEED; // seed for mersenne twister
  string latt_; // which lattice 
  PARAMS();//constructor
};

class LATTICE
{
public:
  LATTICE(const PARAMS&);//constructor
  int Nsite;// number of lattice sites
  int Lx,Ly;
  vector<vector<int> > nrnbrs;
  void print ();

};

class CLUSTER
{
public:
  CLUSTER(const PARAMS&, const LATTICE&);//constructor
  void grow(const PARAMS&, const LATTICE&, MTRand&);
  void meas_clear(const LATTICE&);
  void meas(const LATTICE&);
  void binwrite(const PARAMS&, const LATTICE&);
  //void print(const LATTICE& latt, int index);
  void print(const PARAMS& p, const LATTICE& latt);
  ~CLUSTER();// destructor
//private:
  int size;
  vector <int> conf;
  vector <int> stack;
  double pr;
  //int stck_pnt,stck_end;
  double avg_size;
  ofstream dfout;
  vector <int> stck_pnt;
  vector <int> stck_end;
  int z, pnt, prob, val, row, column;
  vector< vector< vector <int> > > imax; 
};






int main(void)
{
  PARAMS p;
  LATTICE latt(p);
  CLUSTER cluster(p,latt);
  MTRand ran(p.SEED);

  latt.print();
  /*for (int bin=0;bin<p.Nbin;bin++)
    {
      cluster.meas_clear(latt);
      for(int clust=0;clust<p.Nclust;clust++)
    {
      cluster.grow(p,latt,ran);
      cluster.meas(latt);

    }
      cluster.binwrite(p,latt);
    }
*/
  cluster.grow(p, latt, ran);
  cluster.print(p,latt);


}





PARAMS::PARAMS(){
  //initializes commonly used parameters from a file
  ifstream pfin;
  pfin.open("param.dat");  
  if (pfin.is_open()) { 
    pfin >> Nlin;
    pfin >> pr;
    pfin >> Nclust;
    pfin >> Nbin;
    pfin >> SEED;
    pfin >> latt_;
  }
  else
    {cout << "No input file to read ... exiting!"<<endl;exit(1);}
  pfin.close();
  // print out all parameters for record
  cout << "--- Parameters at input for percolation problem ---"<<endl; 
  cout <<"Nlin = "<<Nlin<<"; prob. of site = "<<pr<<endl;
  cout <<"Number of clusters in a bin = "<<Nclust<<"; Number of bins = "<<Nbin<<endl;
  cout <<"RNG will be given SEED of = "<<SEED<<endl;
  cout <<"Percolation problem on lattice --> "<<latt_<<endl;
};//constructor


LATTICE::LATTICE (const PARAMS& p)
{


  string latt_=p.latt_;

  if(p.latt_=="sqlatt_PBC")
    {
      Lx=p.Nlin;Ly=p.Nlin;
      Nsite=Lx*Ly;
      int i;

      nrnbrs = vector<vector<int> >(Nsite, vector<int>(4));

      for (i=0; i<Nsite; i++){

        if((i+1) % p.Nlin != 0) nrnbrs[i][0] = i+1;
          else nrnbrs[i][0] = i - p.Nlin + 1 ;
        if(i + p.Nlin < Nsite ) nrnbrs[i][1] = i+p.Nlin;
          else nrnbrs[i][1] = i - (Nsite-p.Nlin);
        if(i % p.Nlin > 0) nrnbrs[i][2] = i-1;
          else nrnbrs[i][2] = i-1+p.Nlin;
        if(i - p.Nlin >= 0) nrnbrs[i][3] = i-p.Nlin;
          else nrnbrs[i][3] = i + (Nsite-p.Nlin);


      }
    }
  else if(p.latt_=="sqlatt_OBC")
    {
      Lx=p.Nlin;Ly=p.Nlin;
      Nsite=Lx*Ly;

      nrnbrs = vector<vector<int> >(Nsite, vector<int>(0));

      for (int i=0; i<Nsite; i++){

        if((i+1) % p.Nlin != 0){ 
          nrnbrs[i].push_back(i+1);
          }
        if(i + p.Nlin < Nsite ){
          nrnbrs[i].push_back(i+p.Nlin);
          }

        if(i % p.Nlin > 0){
          nrnbrs[i].push_back(i-1);
          }
        if(i - p.Nlin >= 0){
          nrnbrs[i].push_back(i-p.Nlin);
          }
      }

    }
  else
    {cout <<"Dont know your option for lattice in param.dat .. exiting"<<endl;exit(1);}
}




void LATTICE::print()
{
  //THIS FUNCTIONS MAY BE CALLED DURING DEBUGGING TO MAKE SURE LATTICE HAS BEEN DEFINED CORRECTLY
  cout <<"---printing out properties of lattice ---"<<endl;
  cout<<"size is  "<<Lx<<"x"<<Ly<<endl;
  cout <<"neighbors are"<<endl;
  for (int site=0;site<Nsite;site++)
    {
      cout <<site<<" : ";
      for (size_t nn=0;nn<nrnbrs.at(site).size();nn++)
    cout<<nrnbrs.at(site).at(nn)<<" ";
      cout <<endl;
    }
  cout << endl;
}





CLUSTER::CLUSTER(const PARAMS& p, const LATTICE& latt)
{
  conf.resize(latt.Nsite);
  stack.resize(latt.Nsite);
  pr=p.pr;// store prob in a private member of cluster
  dfout.open("data.out");
}




CLUSTER::~CLUSTER()
{
  dfout.close();
}






void CLUSTER::grow(const PARAMS& p, const LATTICE& latt, MTRand& ran)
{
    conf.resize(latt.Nsite);                         // Initalize Nsite elements of lattice to 0 in conf
                                                     // 0 = Not Asked; 1 = Asked, Joined; 2 = Asked, Refused
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Nclust; ++i) {                  // Iterate for Nclust values
        z = ran.randInt(latt.Nsite - 1);               // Random integer between 0 and Nsite; Selects first lattice element in the cluster algorithm per Nclus
        stck_pnt.resize(0);                          // Set stck_pnt and stck_end vectors to size 0; Will be filled when iterating through each Nclust 
        stck_end.resize(0);                          //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //while (conf[z] != 0) { z = ran.randInt(latt.Nsite - 1); }         // Iterate through lattice elements until we select one that has not been asked to join 

        conf[z] = 1;                            // Set element z in conf to have been asked to join and accepted

        stck_pnt.push_back(z);                      // Add z to both stck_pnt and stck_end
        stck_end.push_back(z);
        for (int j = 0; j = 3; ++j) {                // Add z's nearest neighbors to stck_end; Ignore if already been asked
            if (conf[latt.nrnbrs[z][j] == 0]) {
                stck_end.push_back(latt.nrnbrs[z][j]);
            }
        }


        pnt = 1;                                        // Initialize pnt for trasnferral of stack_end values to stck_pnt


        while (stck_pnt.size() < stck_end.size()) {

            stck_pnt.push_back(stck_end[pnt]);     // Add pnt element of stck_end to stck_pnt

            double prob = ran.rand();                      // Get probability value for testing if cluster grows

            if (prob <= pr) {

                conf[stck_pnt[pnt]] = 1;            // Set the current stck_pnt element to joined in conf

                for (int j = 0; j = 3; ++j) {                // Add z's nearest neighbors to stck_end; Ignore if already been asked

                    if (find(stck_end.begin(), stck_end.end(), latt.nrnbrs[stck_pnt[pnt]][j]) != stck_end.end()) {

                        // The given value already exists in stck_end, don't add it again 
                    }

                    else {                          // The given value is not contained in stck_end, add it to stck_end

                        stck_end.push_back(latt.nrnbrs[z][j]);
                    }
                }
            }

            else {

                conf[stck_pnt[pnt]] = 2;       // Set the given value to haven been asked and refused in conf
            }
            ++pnt;                              // Increment pnt; ++p is more efficient then p++ due to lack of copying value
        }

    }
}


/*
    void CLUSTER::print(const LATTICE& latt, int index)
    {

        stringstream ss;
        string file_name;
        ss << index << ".clust";
        file_name = ss.str();

        ofstream clout;
        clout.open(file_name.c_str());
        clout << "#" << latt.Lx << " x " << latt.Ly << endl;

        for (int y = 0; y < latt.Ly; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < latt.Lx; x++)
                clout << conf[x + y*latt.Lx] << " ";
            clout << endl;
        }

        clout.close();
    }
    */


void CLUSTER::print(const PARAMS& p, const LATTICE& latt)
{
    //vector< vector< vector<int> > > imax(latt.Lx, vector< vector<int>>(latt.Ly, vector<int>(1)));
    //  Resize and allocate memeory for imax

    //-------------- Row = y-position = i/Lx --------------- Column = x-position = i%Lx ---------------- val = conf[i]
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("imax.out");

    cout << "THe following output was calculated for the input parameters; Recorded to 'imax.out'" << endl;
    cout <<"[index]" << "\t" << "[x-position]" << "\t" << "[y-position]" << "\t" << "[conf val]" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < latt.Nsite; ++i) {

        val = conf[i];                            // Find color value
        row = i / latt.Lx;                               // Find row number
        column = i%latt.Lx;                            // Find column number

        cout << i << "\t" << column << "\t" << row << "\t" << val << endl;
        myFile << i << "\t" << column << "\t" << row << "\t" << val << endl;
    }
    myFile.close();
    double size = 0.0;                                       // Initialize size 

    for (int i = 0; i < latt.Nsite; ++i) {

        if (conf[i] == 1) {
            size += 1;
        }
    }

    double avg_size = size / p.Nclust;                 // Find avg_size 


}

void CLUSTER::meas(const LATTICE& latt)
{
  avg_size+=(double)size;
}


void CLUSTER::meas_clear(const LATTICE& latt)
{
  avg_size=0.;
}


void CLUSTER::binwrite(const PARAMS& p, const LATTICE& latt)
{
  dfout << avg_size/((double)p.Nclust)<<endl;
}
```

When I set Nclust=0 in the input file, the code runs as expected and gives the proper output in the file and console. However, when I set Nclust equal to any other value, I get the proper lattice console output but the program hangs for the cluster algorithm. I at first assumed that my computer and algorithm were slow and inefficient and that the program was working in some non-linear time. However, after leaving the program running for around 30 minutes for a 4x4 lattice (only 16 elements in the conf[] vector), no progress had been made and I assumed that the program was stuck in a loop.

After spending several hours going over the CLUSTER::grow() method line-by-line and experimenting with changing various bits of code, I have been unable to resolve where this loop error originates from. I would assume it is somewhere in the while loop that compares the size of stck_pnt and stck_end, but I cannot figure out why or where this is. Any help with this would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got tl:dr version?

Comment: Tl;dr:  For Nclust !=0, CLUSTER:grow gets stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Have you already tried a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

> Tl;dr: For Nclust !=0, CLUSTER:grow gets stuck in an infinite loop

You have infinite loop here:

```
 stck_end.push_back(z);
    for (int j = 0; j = 3; ++j) {  // <======== HERE
```

and here:

```
conf[stck_pnt[pnt]] = 1;            // Set the current stck_pnt element to joined in conf

                for (int j = 0; j = 3; ++j) { // <======== HERE
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t realize that I had left out the proper conditional.